# Passing arguments from shell to embedded Python scripts

Tags: python, bash, shell, zsh

I wrote a shell function, intended to be compatible with both zsh and bash:

```
py () { python -c 'print($1)'; }
```

but when i use `py hello`, I get an error from the Python interpreter:

```
➜  ~  py hello
  File "<string>", line 1
    print($1)
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Don't use string substitution at all -- that way lies (a cousin of) [Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/). Instead, pass arguments out-of-band:

```
py() { python -c 'import sys; print sys.argv[1]' "$@"; }
py hello
```

To demonstrate why the other approach is dangerous:

```
py() { python -c "print('${1}')"; }
py "hello' + str(__import__('os').system('touch /tmp/broke-your-security')) + '"
```

When run, this code creates a file `/tmp/broke-your-security`. Consider what would happen if that command instead involved `rm -rf`, or `curl | sh` to pull down a rootkit.

Comment: hi! i am not using this function in production, just for personal use :)

Comment: @sindhus, sure, but you'll _eventually_ be writing production code, no? Better to be in good habits before it matters. :)